# How to add sliding and faster scrolling to a ScrollView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, scrollview

I use a `ScrollView` in the layout of a fragment, but the scrolling is much slower than in the most other apps and it doesn't slide at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/content" />

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `@layout/content`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

      <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_margin="8dp"
             android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
             cardview:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:focusable="true">

             <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:padding="6dp">

                   <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_24dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                     android:layout_weight="0.9"
                     android:orientation="vertical"
                     android:padding="4dp">

                         <TextView
                          android:id="@+id/view_more"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="View more" />
                     </LinearLayout>
                 </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
      </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your `content` layout.

Comment: I've added the content layout

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `NestedScrollView` in your case, as you are having a `RecyclerView` inside your `ScrollView`. Please modify the parent layout as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <NestedScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/content" />

    </NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: he has a v7 API change it to `NestedScrollView`